# using sqlite with php and sqlite-programs

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite with php.

I used some tutorial:

```
$db = sqlite_open("db.sqlite");

sqlite_query($db , "CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name CHAR(255))");

sqlite_query($db, "INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('Ilia')");
sqlite_query($db, "INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('Ilia2')");
sqlite_query($db, "INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('Ilia3')");

$result = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT * FROM foo");

while ($row = sqlite_fetch_array($result)) print_r($row);
```

It works, but file db.sqlite can't be opened by any sqlite program.
And vice-versa, files that were created by sqlite programs can't be opened with php sqlite_open:

> Warning: sqlite_open()
>   [function.sqlite-open]: file is
>   encrypted or is not a database in
>   ...\public_html\test\test.php
>   on line 2

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Maybe it's the SQLite version?**

`sqlite_open()` only creates / reads SQLite 2 databases.

I suggest you move to the far better [`sqlite:` (version 3) and `sqlite2:` (version 2) PDO drivers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php).